# Fixed.pars meaning rmGarch

Tags: r, forecasting, volatility

I'm an italian student using rmgarch package for forecasting covariance matrix. While using ugarchspec function for defining input parameters of univariate GARCH model using a t-Student distribution, I have noticed that there is a parameter called fixed.pars. 
Following the example given in GitHub this parameter is set as following:

fixed.pars = list(shape = 5)

in case of a t-Student distribution. If i change this setting from 5 to 3 (for example) results are very different: can someone tell me the importance and the usage of this parameter?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you're using parameter two different ways here. `fixed.pars` is an argument that allows you to fix one or more parameters from the distribution. `fixed.pars` allows you to conduct statistical tests on the parameters (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234738/dcc-garch-how-to-test-restricted-vs-unrestricted-model-with-lr-test) and is required to run some DCC functions (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmgarch/rmgarch.pdf).

For the shape parameter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_parameter), uGARCHmultispec finds a common shape parameter based on your input list of univariate GARCH specifications. Using `fixed.pars` largely overrides that process and restricts the shape to whatever you specify it to be. You can see the effect of changing shape parameters on different distributions at http://www.randomservices.org/random/apps/SpecialCalculator.html.

Comment: Dear @cgrafe, thanks for your answer! According to your link, I can suppose that the shape parameter is linked to degrees of freedom of the t-Student distribution. I have never heard of "shape", but I have always referred to t-Student using its degrees of freedom. In other words, can I assume that the parameter "shape" I'm passing to the function represents the number of degrees of freedom of the distribution?

Comment: Not exactly, as I understand it. The shape is determined by the degrees of freedom, but the shape parameter (in the multivariate t distribution) is derived from your univariate inputs. You can see the shape matrix and relationship to df in the upper right at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution.